# How can make a task run every hour on the dot?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, task, python-asyncio

I'm running a discord bot, and I want my bot to run a task every hour on the dot.
I tried using `tasks.loop(hours=1.0)`, but the period of this loop is terribly inaccurate and gets even worse over time.
How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Must this be done inside the code? Because outside of it you can use [task scheduler](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-create-automated-task-using-task-scheduler-windows-10) on windows or a [cron job](https://linuxhint.com/schedule_linux_task/) in linux.

Comment: Why was this question closed @PeterWood? It’s not really a duplicate of that... It’s vague, needs details, but I wouldn’t close it as a duplicate.

Comment: @bluevulture Yes I need it done inside the code, especially inside async function.  
That duplicate question is not helping me much :(

Comment: @Ultim8_Clock your task is a bit difficult, as you're using python. In any other language I would suggest a second thread to act as a sort of timer (checking time elapsed in a loop) and then calling an event.

Comment: @ŁukaszKwieciński can you find a more appropriate duplicate? I'm sure they exist. If OP edits the question, provides better details, and explains why the duplicate doesn't help, I'm sure it can be reopened.

Comment: Also, see [ask], how to create a [mcve].